# Maven : How to decrease jar size in maven-project?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3

We are converting legacy application from On Premise to Cloud.

New Cloud offering has a Micro service architecture. In order to reuse some of the existing code we have used one of the Modules (Base Module - Common code) from On-Prem Project and added it as a dependency in most of Micro services.

The problem here is - Size of the base module dependency is too large roughly 150 MB and since it is included in multiple micro services the fat jar created for most of micro services is also large which in turn increases the overall size.

The size of Base Module is large because it has many source files and lot of third party dependencies.

We tried removing the unnecessary code and keeping only required classes and third party jars but since it is legacy code there are lot of interdependent classes and this thing is just not working even after spending lot of time on cleanup.

Is there any another way to decrease the size of all micro service's jar ?

Although I know it is compile time dependency but still - Something like only one fat jar created for Base Module and that is referenced by other micro services but that base module's fat jar is not bundled in each micro service's jar.

Or any other options

Comment: What do you mean by `The size of Base Module is large because it has many source files and lot of third party dependencies.` Do you package the source files in your jar file? Why using fat jars as dependencies for others thats the wrong way... never do that....